# Rover And specimen C#

Tags: c#

i am making a simple game of rover, in which i am having a simple problem which i can't figured out

This is my Main Function which is making One rover object in which rover can handle multiple device, there is one device which extract the specimen

```
      Rover rov = new Rover();
        string input;
        //Device d = new Device();
        //Specimen spec = new Specimen();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Planetary Rover");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter y to start the game or n to exit");
        string selection = Console.ReadLine();
        if (selection == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the rover Default Location X: ");
            rov.X = 

            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Write the device nname to operate ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                rov.Handle(input);
                //d.Operate();
            } while (input != "end");
        }
        if (selection == "n")
        { 
            Console.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input!");
        }
```

THe drill is the device which extraxt the specimen whenever it is operated, it only extract if the specimen x and y is equals to rover x and y
I have done these thing but in my drill class there is operate functionwhich is doing the above thing, but problems occurs whenever drill is operating it is again making a new rover, so the rover x and y get null that time, so any can give me a potential fixes for that how can i use the existing rover in the drill function

```
    public override void Operate(string ids)
    {
        Rover rov = new Rover();




        if (specim.X == rov.X && specim.Y == rov.Y)
        {
            _wearfactor += 5;
            Console.WriteLine("specimen extracted and wearfaction of drill is incresed by 5%");
            Console.WriteLine(_wearfactor);
            _spec. = 0;

        }

        if(specim.X != rov.X && specim.Y != rov.Y)
        {
            _wearfactor += 10;
            Console.WriteLine("wear factor increased by 10%");
            Console.WriteLine(_wearfactor);
        }
        if (_wearfactor == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drill Destroyed");
            Console.WriteLine("syart your program again");
            Console.WriteLine("You can not drill specimen now");
            this.Name = "";

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your Operate method's signature to:

```
    public override void Operate(Rover rov, string ids)
```

then when you create `Rover rov = new Rover();` you can pass it through for `Operate` to use.

```
    Operate(rov, "ids");
```

---

Another option would be to make a public Rover object and directly reference it through `Operate`:

```
// assuming your main class is MainFunction
public class MainFunction()
{
    public Rover rov { get; private set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Establish the reusable rover
        rov = new Rover();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Then in `Operate`, change all `rov` to `MainFunction.rov`